# Symfony on heroku fail to install packages on push

Tags: git, symfony, heroku, composer-php

I can't push my project on heroku because it fails on build because of packages.
Could anyone help me making this working. I've tried to add this to my composer.json `"ext-intl": "*"`

Thanks for your help!

```
Pushing to git@heroku.com:myproject.git
Initializing repository, done.

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> PHP app detected
-----> Resolved composer.lock requirement for PHP >=5.3.3 to version 5.6.1.
-----> Installing system packages...
       - PHP 5.6.1
       - Apache 2.4.10
       - Nginx 1.6.0
-----> Installing PHP extensions...
       - zend-opcache (automatic; bundled, using 'ext-zend-opcache.ini')
-----> Installing dependencies...
       Composer version 73e9db5d9952d52a46ecbc20a269a8c5f9c5b011 2014-10-07 15:03:19
       Loading composer repositories with package information
       Installing dependencies from lock file
       Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

         Problem 1
           - Installation request for symfony/icu v1.2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[v1.2.1].
           - symfony/icu v1.2.1 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
         Problem 2
           - symfony/icu v1.2.1 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
           - symfony/symfony v2.4.3 requires symfony/icu ~1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[v1.2.1].
           - Installation request for symfony/symfony v2.4.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.4.3].


 !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `lib-icu` package in the system where you are deploying. This is a very common issue, that you will need to solve in the server layer, not in your application.

There is a manual page dedicated to dealing with this problem: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html